# I updated my system just now.But the updating software says me that updates were installed 3days ago.

Tags: updates

Please recommend me what kind of updates are not needed.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Most likely there are no updates for your system at the moment. Looks for me like normal behaiviour of ubuntu-ubdate. If youre impatiant you may hit the "check" button. Then your software database may get new entries to install via update-manager

Sorry of course it is update-manager and not ubuntu-update. its the prog wich are shown in your first post

Comment: What's `ubuntu-update`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try clearing apt-get's cache and forcing it to redownload the package list by running the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get clean
cd /var/lib/apt
sudo mv lists lists.old
sudo mkdir -p lists/partial
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
```

This will force it to redownload the package lists, giving you the latest and greatest packages from the server.

You DO know the difference between

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Right?